# Parent not Successfully Retrieving Data from Child

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a callback function in a parent component passed to an child component that should retrieve the input once submission in the child component takes place but is not working as expected. No data is being retrieved by the parent. Here is my code:

Parent:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
     this.state = { item: '' }
  }

  getItem(item) {
    this.setState({
      item: item
    })
    console.log(this.state.item);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Input getItem={this.getItem} />
      <h2>{this.state.item}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Child:

```
class Input extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { value: '' }
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    })
    console.log(this.state.value)
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    {this.props.getItem(this.state.value)};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            <input type="text" name={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="+" />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind the `getItem` context to the `App` class.

You can do this by doing

```
<Input getItem={this.getItem.bind(this)} />
```

or by using the arrow function when you define `getItem`

or by binding the method in the constructor as you did for the child component

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1 :**

Use fat arrow in `getItem` function like this :

```
getItem = (item) => {
   this.setState({
      item: item
   })
   console.log(this.state.item);
}
```

**Solution 2 :**
Bind `getItem` function in counstructor like :

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props)
 this.state = { item: '' }
 this.getItem = this.getItem.bind(this);
}
```

**Solution 3 :**

Bind `getItem` function in input directly :

```
<Input getItem={this.getItem.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: Great, Three ways we can bind a function. Fat arrow solution seems more time-saving!!!